# how to display a android progress bar while checking server connectivity

Tags: android, progress-bar

I wanna display a progress bar while checking server connectivity, I include a progress bar to avoid the blank screen while the system is checking the connection. I wrote the code as shown below but it's still not the things I wanted. I have tried so many ways but I didn't make it, how to do it right ? what's wrong with my code, please ?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Handler handler;
private ProgressDialog progress;
private Context context;
ProgressBar progressBar;
public class BackgroundAsyncTask extends
        AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    int myProgress;

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "onPostExecute", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "onPreExecute", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        myProgress = 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while (myProgress < 100) {
            myProgress++;
            publishProgress(myProgress);
            SystemClock.sleep(100);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
    }
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (IsReachable(this)) {
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        new BackgroundAsyncTask().execute();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Server on ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Seconde.class);
        startActivity(i);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "server off ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.net.vpn.SETTINGS");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

public static boolean IsReachable(Context context) {
    // First, check we have any sort of connectivity
    final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final NetworkInfo netInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isReachable = false;

    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
        // Some sort of connection is open, check if server is reachable
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://google.com");//test

            HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android Application");
            urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            urlc.setConnectTimeout(2 * 1000);
            urlc.connect();
            isReachable = (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    return isReachable;
}


}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not really possible to calculate a percentage of time while connecting to a server - because who knows how long the server will respond. I would recommend showing an  indeterminate progress bar (which just animates in a loop without showing any kind  of percentage of progress). The only other time you could effectively use a progress bar would be downloading a file - since you know what the total length is, and can make predictions based off the current download speed (or just show a percent).

Comment: how can i showing an indeterminate progress bar please ?

Comment: setIndeterminate(true) I think. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

Answer (score 0):

In your layout, add the progress bar

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleInverse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

And in your code, when you are checking the server, just set the progress bar visible

```
mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Then when you done with checking the server, set progress bar to gone

```
mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Note: The style of progress bar depend on your app theme style

Comment: Fuyuba i did what you said but i get a blank screen

Comment: This is indeterminate progress bar, so you don't need to setProgress() anymore

Comment: i juste wanna display a simple progressbar beside of a blank activity